# Tax Query trouble

Tags: taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I can't seem to figure this out.

The following query works:

```
$xxxx = new WP_Query(array(
'listset' => 'homepage',
'meta_query' => array(
    array (
        'key' => 'show_home',
        'value' => 'true',
        'compare' => '='
    )
),
'posts_per_page' => 1,
'post_type' => 'lists',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'orderby' => 'date',
'order' => 'DESC'
));
```

The following does not:

```
$xxxx = new WP_Query(array(
'tax_query' => array(
    array (
        'taxonomy' => 'listset',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'homepage'
    )
),
'meta_query' => array(
    array (
        'key' => 'show_home',
        'value' => 'true',
        'compare' => '='
    )
),
'posts_per_page' => 1,
'post_type' => 'lists',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'orderby' => 'date',
'order' => 'DESC'
));
```

Anyone can help me figure out why the second one doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

The `terms` for the `tax_query` should be an array.

Comment: Still doesn't fix it and according to the help doc, it doesn't need to be:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Ah, and I definitely meant to leave this as a comment, not an answer. Oh well :)

Comment: Should I convert it to a comment?

Comment: @toscho: If you'd like. It sort of stands as an answer (in my experience, I've needed to use an array and not just a string, even for a single term), but then I should probably flesh it out more.

Comment: Your decision. I’d rather see a good answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You say that "the second one doesn't work", but it's not clear in what way it doesn't work, and in what way you expect it to work. The query you've put together will only match posts that BOTH have listset = 'homepage' AND show_home = 'true'. Are you sure that there are posts in your database where this is true? Is this what you mean to be querying?

I don't think that it's possible to do an OR between meta_query and tax_query using `WP_Query` alone. You would probably have to either do two queries (the first would give the `post__in` parameter for the second) or filter `posts_where` and do some fancy regex.

Comment: I mean it doesn't work in that query1 returns results while query2 returns nothing.

And yes, that is the query I want.  listset = homepage (taxonomy) and show_home = true (meta field data).

Comment: You mean it literally returns *nothing*? Or it returns a `WP_Query` object with empty results?